# backbone view not accessible through console while declared in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, console

Getting an error trying to get declared view (model and collection as well) in jquery

```
var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function(){
    this.model = new PageModel();
},

});

$(function() {
var pageView = new PageView();
});
```

in console using pageView (simply typing pageView) getting an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: pageView is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

without jquery works great.

i know that it's basics, but cannot figure it out.
thanks in advance

Comment: Need more code to debug.

Comment: very simple. added PageView view init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That common bit we put at the start of jquery code:

```
$(function() {
    // ...
});
```

that means execute this function when the DOM is ready, and the function passed in as an argument really is a function definition... thus it has it's own scope distinct from the global scope.

Your variable is defined in the function, and remains undefined in the global scope. If you want access to the variable in the global scope, but don't want to initialize it early you can do this:

```
var pageView = false;
$(function() {
    pageView = new PageView();
});
```

Comment: getting false. and not the backbone object